# JavaScript Differentiate Between Page Refresh, Browser Close and New tab

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to Differentiate Between Page Refresh, Browser Close and New tab events.

So, I want some handling on page close V/s page refresh/new tab

I came across below workaround using sessionStorage. However the issue with sessionStorage is that it gets reset or is not read even on opening link in new tab. But I want both page refresh/new tab to behave in same way V/s refresh of the page.

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('reloaded') != null) {
    console.log('page was reloaded');
} else {
    console.log('page was not reloaded');
}

sessionStorage.setItem('reloaded', 'yes');
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve. This is too general. In short, you can use `sessionStorage` to track page refresh only as it gets cleared on tab close. You can sync this data with `localStorage` to handle other states but really depends on what exactly you're trying to do. Give more context.

Comment: I want some JS state to be retained on page refresh/new tab, but removed on page close

Comment: By "page close" you mean tab close? Otherwise, please define what you understand by "page close".

Comment: Yes, close is both page close and tab close...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a combination of `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` to persist the data and rely on [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event to handle the data removal.

The thing is `beforeunload` fires on both tab/window close **and page refresh** so we have to work around that.

`localStorage` will handle persistence across tabs and windows and `sessionStorage` will sync the data on page refresh.

```
const readFromStorage = (storageKey) => {
    const localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
    const sessionStorageItem = sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey);

    // You can optimize this by doing more checks but you get the idea
    const itemValue = localStorageItem ?? sessionStorageItem;

    if (localStorageItem !== sessionStorageItem) {
        writeToStorage(storageKey, itemValue);
    }

    return itemValue;
};

const writeToStorage = (storageKey, value) => {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, value);
    sessionStorage.setItem(storageKey, value);
};
```

Event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
    localStorage.removeItem(STORAGE_KEY);
});
```

Usage:

```
const STORAGE_KEY = '<storage_key>';

const item = readFromStorage(STORAGE_KEY);
```

If `item` is `null` - a tab/windows was closed. Otherwise, the data will persist across refreshes and new tabs/windows.

Comment: Thanks...Let me have a look...but just wondering what does localStorageItem ?? sessionStorageItem mean?

Comment: Also just one more thing to add, on page refresh (or even new tab open for that matter), there is a server call which gets this same state value...So just thinking about that as well....Like on page refresh (but not on initial/first load), read/use the local state value (instead of what the server gives)